# support multiple resolutions in android with 160 dp

Tags: android, resolutions

My application must support for two resolutions, they are

1920x1080 & 1024x768. For this I  created layouts and value folder separately like this

`layout-w1920dp-mdpi & values-w1920dp-mdpi for 1920x1080`

```
layout-w1024dp-mdpi && values-w1920dp-mdpi for 1024x768
```

But these are not reflecting for my app. How create application which shold support both resolution and both resolutions are 160 dp.

Thanks

Comment: you're making confusion with the identifier of the folders, you're specifying both screen size, not resolution, and screen density, they both depend on resolution and screen size. they're not going to identify resources based on resolution only

Comment: @lelloman thanks for your feedback. How to name the folders for different resolutions

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, you could check screen size programmatically though. Screen resolution is not an important factor, size and density are.

Comment: @lelloman if I get screen size  programitically how to keep resources ?

Comment: you can put 2 versions of the resources, check the screen size at run time and decide which one you want to load